# Setting jobconf parameters with Karmasphere Analyst & Amazon Elastic MapReduce

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

The Karmasphere Analyst profiler has suggested that I set some jobconf parameters, for example, mapred.map.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec. But I don't know where to set these and I can't find it in the Karmasphere Analyst documentation.

I tried setting it in Access->Configuration->Extra Settings but it did not seem to have any effect. I also tried putting this in the "Additional Parameters" field when in the "New Cloud Connection" window (as a JSON string, {mapred.map.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec}), but this caused a silent failure and the jobflow didn't start.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the option in "Extra Settings" and add needed jar file to Classes/Resource tab of you cluster connection configuration.